# I cannot load a Mass Effect 3 save on PC. Says I am missing DLC

Tags: mass-effect-3

The full description when I click resume game or load a save is "the selected save game cannot be loaded. the following downloadable content is missing: from ashes". I click downloadable content on the ME3 title screen and I scroll down to the bottom and it says I own the "From Ashes" dlc, so I don't understand why it's doing this. I'm connected to the EA servers also.

I tried right clicking on the my games section of Origin and selecting the repair function on ME3. That didn't fix it and I've tried re-installing it, still to no avail though.

Comment: I can believe that saying you own "From Ashes" is different from saying you have "From Ashes" installed.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Origin and download From Ashes DLC. If it doesn't work, remove the DLC and install it again.